# Wondering if I can improve this PHP function?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, magento-1, performance

I've added a function to a custom module and I'm just wondering if I can improve the code.

The function basically gets the collection of items (products) from the order and checks to see if any of them have a custom attribute, called DeliveryOption, with the value 'JKLMN', if it does it returns false.

```
public function checkForTrackingCode()
{
    $_productObject = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $_isAnPost = true;
    foreach ($this->getItemsCollection()->getItems() as $item) {
        $_product = $_productObject->loadByAttribute('sku', $item->getSku());
        if ($_product->getDeliveryOptionValue() != "JKLMN") {
            $_isAnPost = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $_isAnPost;
}
```

Specifically I'm wondering **if I should load the `$productObject` or rather just do it in the foreach loop with**:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $item->getSku());
```

My thinking was if I put the Product Object into `$productObject`  it would save on resources rather than having to do it each time in the `foreach` loop, is this correct?

Also, I tried getting `DeliveryOptionValue` straight from the `itemsCollection` with from the `$item->getProduct()->getDeliveryOptionValue();` but that just returned `null`, I thought that should have worked.

I should mention that our Module Class extends from `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` so `$this` is the `salesOrder` Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the best improvement would be to not have to load anything at all.
("The best shovel is an already dug hole in the ground").
When doing a checkout process you should copy the value of `delivery_option_value` from the product to the quote item and from quote item to order item (and maybe shipment item, invoice item and creditnote item).
Placed orders should be a snapshot of the products at that moment in time. When performing actions on the ordered items you should not touch the actual product because theoretically the product can be changed or deleted.

For this, you need to add one more column to the `sales_quote_item`, `sales_order_item`, `sales_invoice_item`, `sales_shipment_item` and `sales_creditmemo_item` called `delivery_option_value`.

To make the value persists from quote to order to invoice to shipment to creditmemo you need to add in one of your `config.xml` files this under the `global` tag, this:

```
<fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_item>
        <delivery_option_value>
            <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
        <delivery_option_value>
    </sales_convert_quote_item>
    <sales_convert_order_item>
        <delivery_option_value>
            <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
            <to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item>
            <to_shipment_item>*</to_shipment_item>
            <to_cm_item>*</to_cm_item>
        </delivery_option_value>
    </sales_convert_order_item>
</fieldsets>
```

and to copy the value from the product to the quote item you can use the event `sales_quote_item_set_product` that is dispatched in the [quote item  model `setProduct` method](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php#L399) and receives as parameter the product and the quote item.

```
public function addDeliveryOptionValue($observer)
{
    $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $quoteItem->setDeliveryOptionValue($product->getDeliveryOptionValue());
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Performance Improvement

Loading products in a loop is very bad, specially when you only need one attribute value.

Huge improvement can be done by replacing:

```
$_product = $_productObject->loadByAttribute('sku', $item->getSku());
```

With:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('delivery_option_value')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $item->getSku())
    ->setPageSize(1)
    ->setCurPage(1);

if (!$collection->getSize()) {
    continue;
}

$_product = $collection->getFirstItem();
```

### Further Improvement

Instead of looping through your items collection to get the sku, I'm pretty sure (you need to test it first) you can get all the skus by doing:

```
$skus = $this->getItemsCollection()->getItems()->getColumnValues('sku');
```

If that works, that means you can replace your entire code with this:

```
public function checkForTrackingCode()
{
    $skus = $this->getItemsCollection()->getItems()->getColumnValues('sku');
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('delivery_option_value', array('neq' => 'JKLMN'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('IN' => $skus))

    return $collection->getSize() ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: thanks but there are a few things I don't understand there, what are `setPageSize(1)` and `setPageSize(1)` for?  And what is `if` clause for? And why would I load the `getFirstItem` from the `$collection`?

Comment: @Holy `setPageSize` is to ensure the collection is limited to 1 object. It's a safety to ensure you load one product. The `if` is another safety in case there is no product matching that sku. `getFirstItem` will give you the first product from the collection and as there is only one (thanks to the `setPageSize`) that's how you load a product via collection. See my edit for further improvements

Comment: and what is `setCurPage(1)` for?

Comment: @Holy to ensure you're on the first page of the collection. An extra safety in case your collection has been modified by some observer

Comment: unfortunatly `$this->getItemsCollection()->getItems()->getColumnValues('sku')` returned an error,  `PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumnValues() on a non-object`, so I will use your first solution, Thanks!

Comment: One last thing, why is loading `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')` within a Loop better than  `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')`?

Comment: @holy what is the class of `getItems()` ? well with my collection you don't need a loop anymore right

Comment: `loadByAttribute` already uses the collection with page size one, so there is not much impovement there: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Abstract.php#L224

Comment: @Marius interesting, I wasn't aware of that. The second part of my answer should be an improvement though. Seems like it's not working though, not sure why